# nested function losing variable reference

Tags: javascript, scope

In the following code:

```
function outer() {
  var x = 'foo';

  function inner() {
    var y = x;     // y == 'foo'
    var x = 'bar'; // x == 'bar', y == undefined
  }
}
```

Why does the variable `y` become undefined within `inner()`? shouldn't it refer to `x` in `outer()`?

If the line `var x = 'bar';` is removed then `y` does indeed have the value 'foo'.

Comment: It's called hoisting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `inner` function is interpreted as if it were written like this:

```
  function inner() {
    var y;
    var x;
    y = x;     // y == undefined
    x = 'bar'; // x == 'bar'
  }
```

The *declarations* are hoisted, but the *initializations* are processed top to bottom. Thus, throughout the entire `inner` function, the symbols `x` and `y` both refer to the variables declared *locally* in that function; in particular `x` is the local `x`, not the one in the enclosing context. When the initializer expression for `y` is evaluated, therefore, `x` is the local `x`, which has not yet been initialized; its initializer expression comes *after* the initializer for `y`.

Comment: Downvoter, let me know if there's something I can explain in more detail.